# Vue CLI: Can I have a v-text-field's value change when another v-text-field changes, but at the same time be able to overwrite it?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have 3 v-text-field. I want t3 to be automatically calculated (`vText1 + vText2`) only if there isn't manual input. If the user writes "230" in `t3`, it should ignore `vTextC`. But if the user deletes what they wrote, `vTextC` should again be the value for the text field.

```
<template>
    <v-text-field ref="t1" v-model="vText1"/>
    <v-text-field ref="t2" v-model="vText2"/>
    <v-text-field ref="t3" value="vTextC"/>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
       data() {
           return {
               vText1 : 0,
               vText2 : 0
           }
       },
       computed:{
           vTextC(){ return this.vText1 + this.vText2}
       }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `@input` event (`@update:modelValue` in Vue 3) to keep track of whether the input was made manually. Then update the value only when not in manual mode:

```js
const ButtonComponent = {
  template: `
  <v-card class="ma-2 pa-2" style="max-width: 400px;">
    <v-text-field type="number" v-model.number="vText1" dense/>
    <v-text-field type="number" v-model.number="vText2" dense/>
    <v-text-field
      type="number"
      :label="isManual ? 'manual' : 'calculated'"
      v-model.number="vText3"
      @input="updateIsManual"
      dense
    />
  </v-card>
 `,
  data() {
    return {
      vText1: 0,
      vText2: 0,
      vText3: 0,
      isManual: false,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    calculateVText3() {
      if (this.isManual) return
      this.vText3 = this.vText1 + this.vText2
    },
    updateIsManual(value) {
      this.isManual = value !== ''
      if (!this.isManual) {
        this.calculateVText3()
      }
    },
  },
  watch: {
    vText1: 'calculateVText3',
    vText2: 'calculateVText3',
  },
}

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  components: {'button-component': ButtonComponent}
})
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@6.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
     <button-component></button-component>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
```

Note that UX-wise, this is a bit messy, as users won't know how to get back from manual input. Have a look at the snippet for an example that uses a checkbox to make it more explicit:

```js
const ButtonComponent = {
  template: `
  <v-card class="ma-2 pa-2" style="max-width: 400px">
    <v-text-field type="number" v-model.number="vText1" dense/>
    <v-text-field type="number" v-model.number="vText2" dense/>
    <v-text-field
      type="number"
      v-model.number="vText3"
      :readonly="calculateField3"
      @focus="calculateField3 = false"
      dense
    >
      <template #append-outer>
        <v-checkbox
          class="mt-0"
          v-model="calculateField3"
          label="calculate automatically"
          @change="$event && calculateVText3()" 
        />
      </template>
    </v-text-field>
  </v-card>
 `,
  data() {
    return {
      vText1: 0,
      vText2: 0,
      vText3: 0,
      calculateField3: true,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    calculateVText3() {
      if (!this.calculateField3) return
      this.vText3 = this.vText1 + this.vText2
    },
  },
  watch: {
    vText1: 'calculateVText3',
    vText2: 'calculateVText3',
  },
}

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  components: {
    'button-component': ButtonComponent
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:100,300,400,500,700,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@6.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-main>
      <button-component></button-component>
    </v-main>
  </v-app>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you. I will add a color chek or something to tell if the input is manual or calculated.